# BeanPostProcessor not called

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, spring-mvc

here's my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com">
       <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="com.coc.frmwk.cmd.Command"/>
       <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="com.coc.apps.sample.dao.SampleDAO"/>
    </context:component-scan>

<bean id="myPostProcessor" class="com.coc.frmwrk.processors.MyPostProcessor">
</beans>
```

I know that when using component-scan, the default scope that will be assigned to the beans is "singleton" unless it's specified otherwise in the xml configuration or using the annotation @Scope, that's cool, but since i've figured out that in my application all the beans implementing a specific interface (com.coc.frmwk.cmd.Command) need to have their scope set to "prototype", so i added a class "ScopeResolver" that implements ScopeMetaDataResolver and i made this little modification to my config.xml so that the container takes into account my scope resolver :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" scope-resolver="com.coc.frmwk.processors.ScopeResolver">
```

My problem is that the BeanPostProcessor used to work perfectly, but it stops being called whenever i add the scope resolver ( context:component-scan base-package="com" **scope-resolver="com.xxx.frmwk.processors.ScopeResolver"** ) and it works again when i omit the stuff in bold.

Any idea on how to make The BeanPostProcessor works when the ScopeResolver is configured ?
Thanks, Mehdi.

**Edit:** here's the content of my scope resolver

```
package com.coc.frmwk.processors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopeMetadata;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopeMetadataResolver;

import com.coc.frmwk.cmd.Command;

public class ScopeResolver implements ScopeMetadataResolver{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ScopeMetadata resolveScopeMetadata(BeanDefinition definition) {
        ScopeMetadata result = new ScopeMetadata();

        Class c= null;
        try {
            c = Class.forName(definition.getBeanClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Command.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
        result.setScopeName("prototype");
        else
        result.setScopeName("singleton");

        System.out.println("[Scope Resolver] " + definition.getBeanClassName() + "[" + result.getScopeName() + "]");

        return result;
    }

}
```

**Edit2:** I want to point out that the BeanPostProcessor is in fact being called, but apparently it works with all the beans except those having their scope changed by the ScopeMeteDataResolver.

Comment: Maybe it would help to diagnose it if you compare actual scope of other beans in container and scope that you have generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found exactly how to solve the problem, but i did find a workaround, this might be useful for anyone having the same issue.
well instead of using a combination of BeanPostProcessor and a MetaDataScopeResolver, i decided to use a BeanFactoryPostProcessor that manages both the scope resolution and the bean processing. 
here'ds the code of the BeanFactoryPostProcessor for anyone interested:

```
@Component
public class OaliaBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for(String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames())
        {
            //Scope resolution
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            Class beanClass= null;
            try {
                beanClass = Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // exception handling goes here
            }
            if (Command.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass))
                beanDefinition.setScope("prototype");

            //Stuff that the BeanPostProcessor do go here
            //..........
            //..........

            System.out.println("[Post Processing] " + beanName + " [" + beanDefinition.getScope() + "]");
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you describe is the behavior I would expect. (At least at startup), the `BeanPostProcessor` is called as soon as a bean is constructed, a prototype scoped bean is only constructed when it is requested. So if you don't use this bean anywhere the `BeanPostProcessor` will not get called.

However judging from what you want you want to modify the recipe (the `BeanDefinition` and not so much the created bean instance). For chancing the recipes you need to use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.

The difference is that a `BeanPostProcessor` operates on bean instances where as the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` works on the bean creation recipes (the `BeanDefinitions`).